# terragrunt before_hook failed to exectute tfsec with passing flags in it

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I need to use tfsec command in before_hook in order to scan my terraform code

Working condition

```
terraform {
      # Before apply, run script.
      before_hook "scan_infra" {
        commands     = ["apply"]
        execute  = ["tfsec"]
      }
```

Non working condition

```
terraform {
  # Before apply, run script.
  before_hook "scan_infra1" {
    commands     = ["apply"]
    execute  = ["tfsec --tfvars-file nsg.tfvars"]
  }
# Before apply, run script.
  before_hook "scan_infra2" {
    commands     = ["apply"]
    execute  = ["tfsec","--tfvars-file", "nsg.tfvars"]
  }
```

throws error like below

```
:network_security_group tfsec$ terragrunt plan
INFO[0000] Executing hook: before_hook                  
ERRO[0000] Error running hook before_hook with message: exec: "tfsec --tfvars-file nsg.tfvars": executable file not found in $PATH 
ERRO[0000] Errors encountered running before_hooks. Not running 'terraform'. 
ERRO[0000] 1 error occurred:
    * exec: "tfsec --tfvars-file nsg.tfvars": executable file not found in $PATH
 
ERRO[0000] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the shell, add "sh", "-c" in front of tfsec